Is there a documented Mongock File Naming Convention?
Looking through the example documentation, it seems that Mongock does not embed any sort of ordering in the ChangeUnit filename.
For example, the "Get Started" docs show the following code snippet:
@ChangeUnit(id="client-initializer", order = "001", author = "mongock")
public class ClientInitializerChange {
  ...
}

Someone coming into a project and creating new migration scripts would not know what order to assign without going into the database or scanning through the migration files to find the latest ChangeUnit.
Rather, it seems more useful to rename ClientInitializerChange.java to something like A001_ClientInitializerChange.java. That way the steps can be sorted and understood incrementally.
Because this is the convention I have seen with migration tools like Flyway, I wonder if this omission is deliberate or if there are any angles I am not considering.

This question, as phrased in the title, is opinion-based and therefore off-topic. Suggest rephrasing the title and question to focus on asking if there's any problems with the naming convention you propose.

Mongock's execution process will sort the ChangeUnits by its order value (@ChangeUnit annotation attribute).
In case there are two or more ChangeUnits with the same order value, then Mongock will sort them by the class canonical name.

thanks for the quick reply. That clarifies the behavior but my question was more from a developer-friendly POV. Do you think a convention of Order in the filename makes sense and is worth including in the documentation

It won't affect Mongock execution, is up to you, but yes, it makes sense to reflect the order in the ChangeUnits filename.
